# Convert YAML definition into a Python FLASK rest service

Tags: python, flask, yaml

Is there any way to convert a YAML restful definition into a Python Flask or any other Python restful service code ?

Example YAML :-

```
basePath: /v2
paths:
  /pet/{petId}:
    get:
      tags:
        - pet
      summary: Find pet by ID
      description: Returns a single pet
      operationId: getPetById
      produces:
        - application/xml
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: petId
          in: path
          description: ID of pet to return
          required: true
          type: integer
          format: int64
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          schema:
            db: 'pets'
        '400':
          description: Invalid ID supplied
        '404':
          description: Pet not found
      security:
        - api_key: []
```

This should output something like this Python Flask implementation

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/v2/pet/")
def getpet(petId):
    return "Pet having petID"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a smaple of the YAML you want to use as source. What is the result you want to get?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Does it work?

Comment: Yeah I have tried to go with Swagger Code generator but it doesn't support Python server stubs. And it only generate template of the rest services described by the YAML.

Comment: It is very possible by using pyaml and a templating solution such as mako, jinja2 or the like.  OpenAPI spec also supports user supplied fields prefixed by `x-` such as `x-data-model` so the possibility are really only limited to your imagination, but it is a roll your own situation, or evaluate tools made by others.